# What is a span in APM?

Tags: apm

From the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/7.12/transaction-spans.html
Spans contain information about the execution of a specific code path. They measure from the start to the end of an activity, and they can have a parent/child relationship with other spans.

But what code paths and what activity?

Answer (score 1):

You have to integrate an APM agent (it's a piece of code) into your code - that's what it's being monitored by APM.